# There is no hyperlinks in checkstyle errors after I run mvn clean package, I just can see plain text and can't click it to go to the code

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, checkstyle

I will be really grateful for your help!

It is a Spring Boot project, I use Maven

[what I can see in terminal]

```
[ERROR] C:\Users\tdenchyk\IdeaProjects\school-diary-app\src\main\java\tdenchyk\schooldiaryapp\repository\StudentRepository.java:7:8: Unused import - tdenchyk.schooldiaryapp.dto.student.StudentResponseDto. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] C:\Users\tdenchyk\IdeaProjects\school-diary-app\src\main\java\tdenchyk\schooldiaryapp\repository\TeacherRepository.java:3:8: Unused import - java.util.List. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] C:\Users\tdenchyk\IdeaProjects\school-diary-app\src\main\java\tdenchyk\schooldiaryapp\repository\TeacherRepository.java:5:8: Unused import - org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] C:\Users\tdenchyk\IdeaProjects\school-diary-app\src\main\java\tdenchyk\schooldiaryapp\repository\TeacherRepository.java:6:8: Unused import - org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] C:\Users\tdenchyk\IdeaProjects\school-diary-app\src\main\java\tdenchyk\schooldiaryapp\repository\TeacherRepository.java:8:8: Unused import - tdenchyk.schooldiaryapp.model.Student. [UnusedImports]
[ERROR] C:\Users\tdenchyk\IdeaProjects\school-diary-app\src\main\java\tdenchyk\schooldiaryapp\service\impl\UserServiceImpl.java:11:8: Unused import - tdenchyk.schooldiaryapp.dto.subject.SubjectRequestDto. [UnusedImports]
```

these links are not clickable and colorless

My plugins in pom.xml are as follows:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>${maven.checkstyle.plugin.configLocation}</configLocation>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    <sourceDirectories>src</sourceDirectories>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.30</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My checkstyle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <property name="severity" value="error"/>

    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>
    <!-- Checks for whitespace                               -->
    <!-- See http://checkstyle.sf.net/config_whitespace.html -->
    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile">
        <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LineLength">
        <property name="max" value="100"/>
        <property name="ignorePattern" value="^package.*|^import.*|a href|href|http://|https://|ftp://"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
        <module name="IllegalTokenText">
            <property name="tokens" value="STRING_LITERAL, CHAR_LITERAL"/>
            <property name="format"
                      value="\\u00(09|0(a|A)|0(c|C)|0(d|D)|22|27|5(C|c))|\\(0(10|11|12|14|15|42|47)|134)"/>
            <property name="message"
                      value="Consider using special escape sequence instead of octal value or Unicode escaped value."/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters">
            <property name="allowEscapesForControlCharacters" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowByTailComment" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowNonPrintableEscapes" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
        <module name="IllegalImport"/>
        <module name="RedundantImport"/>
        <module name="UnusedImports"/>
        <module name="OneTopLevelClass"/>
        <module name="NoLineWrap"/>
        <module name="EmptyBlock">
            <property name="option" value="TEXT"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_SWITCH"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NeedBraces"/>
        <module name="LeftCurly"/>
        <module name="RightCurly">
            <property name="id" value="RightCurlySame"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE,
                    LITERAL_DO"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RightCurly">
            <property name="id" value="RightCurlyAlone"/>
            <property name="option" value="alone"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, STATIC_INIT,
                    INSTANCE_INIT"/>
        </module>
        <module name="WhitespaceAround">
            <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyLambdas" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyMethods" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyTypes" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyLoops" value="true"/>
            <message key="ws.notFollowed"
                     value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not followed by whitespace. Empty blocks may only be represented as '{}' when not part of a multi-block statement (4.1.3)"/>
            <message key="ws.notPreceded"
                     value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
        </module>
        <module name="OneStatementPerLine"/>
        <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
        <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
        <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
        <module name="FallThrough"/>
        <module name="VisibilityModifier">
            <property name="protectedAllowed" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="UpperEll"/>
        <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
        <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
            <property name="allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowMultipleEmptyLines" value="false"/>
            <property name="allowMultipleEmptyLinesInsideClassMembers" value="false"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapDot"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="DOT"/>
            <property name="option" value="nl"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapComma"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="COMMA"/>
            <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <!-- ELLIPSIS is EOL until https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/258 -->
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapEllipsis"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="ELLIPSIS"/>
            <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <!-- ARRAY_DECLARATOR is EOL until https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/259 -->
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapArrayDeclarator"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="ARRAY_DECLARATOR"/>
            <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapMethodRef"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_REF"/>
            <property name="option" value="nl"/>
        </module>
        <module name="PackageName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]+(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Package name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="TypeName">
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="MemberName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Member name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="LambdaParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Lambda parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="CatchParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Catch parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="LocalVariableName">
            <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Local variable name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Class type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodTypeParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Method type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="InterfaceTypeParameterName">
            <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Interface type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="NoFinalizer"/>
        <module name="GenericWhitespace">
            <message key="ws.followed"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is followed by whitespace."/>
            <message key="ws.preceded"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is preceded with whitespace."/>
            <message key="ws.illegalFollow"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' should followed by whitespace."/>
            <message key="ws.notPreceded"
                     value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
        </module>
        <module name="Indentation">
            <property name="basicOffset" value="4"/>
            <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/>
            <property name="caseIndent" value="4"/>
            <property name="throwsIndent" value="8"/>
            <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="8"/>
            <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="4"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AbbreviationAsWordInName">
            <property name="ignoreFinal" value="false"/>
            <property name="allowedAbbreviationLength" value="1"/>
        </module>
        <module name="OverloadMethodsDeclarationOrder"/>
        <module name="VariableDeclarationUsageDistance"/>
        <module name="CustomImportOrder">
            <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
            <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="true"/>
            <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="STATIC###THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="COMMA, SEMI, POST_INC, POST_DEC, DOT, ELLIPSIS, METHOD_REF"/>
            <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParenPad"/>
        <module name="OperatorWrap">
            <property name="option" value="NL"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="BAND, BOR, BSR, BXOR, DIV, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LE, LITERAL_INSTANCEOF, LOR,
                    LT, MINUS, MOD, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, QUESTION, SL, SR, STAR, METHOD_REF "/>
        </module>
        <module name="AnnotationLocation">
            <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationMostCases"/>
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AnnotationLocation">
            <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationVariables"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
            <property name="allowSamelineMultipleAnnotations" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescription"/>
        <module name="MethodName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"/>
            <message key="name.invalidPattern"
                     value="Method name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
        </module>
        <module name="SingleLineJavadoc">
            <property name="ignoreInlineTags" value="false"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EmptyCatchBlock">
            <property name="exceptionVariableName" value="expected"/>
        </module>
        <module name="CommentsIndentation"/>
        <module name="DeclarationOrder"/>
        <module name="SingleSpaceSeparator">
            <property name="validateComments" value="true"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

I double checked pom.xml and checkstyle.xml
I want to be able to clink on the each link and be redirected to the piece of code where I have an error